# How to change the operation name of a span with Apache Camel OpenTracing component?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, jaeger, opentracing

I successfully added Apache Camel's [OpenTracing](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/others/opentracing.html) component to my application. I can see traces in Jaeger UI. But the traces for the [RabbitMQ](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/rabbitmq-component.html) component show only the exchange name without the routing key as operation name. Because of my application uses only one exchange with different routing keys, I need to see the routing key as operation name in my traces.

**Research**

With [OpenTracing Spring RabbitMQ](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq) I could expose another customized [`RabbitMqSpanDecorator`](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq/blob/master/opentracing-spring-rabbitmq/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/rabbitmq/RabbitMqSpanDecorator.java), see [Span decorator](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq#span-decorator):

> Note: you can customize your spans by declaring an overridden `RabbitMqSpanDecorator` bean.

(However, I coulnd't change the operation name with the `RabbitMqSpanDecorator` at all, because the operation name is hard coded to `producer` or `consumer`.)

Unfortunately Apache Camel uses its own different implementation of a [`RabbitmqSpanDecorator`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-tracing/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/tracing/decorators/RabbitmqSpanDecorator.java) to decorate spans. I wrote a custom class by overiding Apache Camel's `RabbitmqSpanDecorator`, but my custom class wasn't used.

**Question**

How can I change the operation name of a span with Apache Camel OpenTracing component for Apache Camel RabbitMQ component?

Comment: Camel uses Java's [service loader API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) in the [Tracer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-tracing/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/tracing/Tracer.java#L58) to actually load the respective decorations. As such, your custom decorator should be picked up if you package your decorator as mentioned in the `Deploying service providers on the class path` section of the JavaDocs

Comment: @RomanVottner Thank you. It works. Would you like to write an  elaborated answer? I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the `Tracer` implementation with `ServiceLoader`, see [OpenTracing](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/others/opentracing.html#_explicit):

> **EXPLICIT**
>
> Include the `camel-opentracing` component in your POM, along with any specific dependencies associated with the chosen OpenTracing compliant Tracer.
>
> To explicitly configure OpenTracing support, instantiate the `OpenTracingTracer` and initialize the camel context. You can optionally specify a `Tracer`, or alternatively it can be implicitly discovered using the `Registry` or `ServiceLoader`.

With the `DefaultTracer` it is also possible to change the `RabbitmqSpanDecorator` with `ServiceLoader`, see [`Tracer.java`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-tracing/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/tracing/Tracer.java#L58):

> ```java
> static {
>     ServiceLoader.load(SpanDecorator.class).forEach(d -> {
>         SpanDecorator existing = DECORATORS.get(d.getComponent());
>         // Add span decorator if no existing decorator for the component,
>         // or if derived from the existing decorator's class, allowing
>         // custom decorators to be added if they extend the standard
>         // decorators
>         if (existing == null || existing.getClass().isInstance(d)) {
>             DECORATORS.put(d.getComponent(), d);
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

Therefore, I had to add a file `org.apache.camel.tracing.SpanDecorator` containing the name of my custom `RabbitmqSpanDecorator`, see [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html):

> **Deploying service providers on the class path**
>
> A service provider that is packaged as a JAR file for the class path is identified by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource directory **META-INF/services**. The name of the provider-configuration file is the fully qualified binary name of the service. The provider-configuration file contains a list of fully qualified binary names of service providers, one per line.

My custom `RabbitmqSpanDecorator`:

```java
public class CustomRabbitmqSpanDecorator extends RabbitmqSpanDecorator {

  @Override
  public String getOperationName(Exchange exchange, Endpoint endpoint) {

    return ((RabbitMQEndpoint) endpoint).getRoutingKey();
  }
}
```